# span tag not getting set using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question . I'm trying to set the span value inside the Javascript but the value that is being  set as NAN

Can any one please help? here is the code

```
$( '#delivery_time' ).change(function() {   
var selectdate = $( '#delivery_time' ).val();
var d = new Date(selectdate);   
if(d.getDay() == 0 || d.getDay() == 6)  {      
   var span = $("ul#shipping_method li span.amount").text();
   var res = span.split("£");
   var newCost = ((parseFloat(res[1])*50)/100) + parseFloat(res[1]); //till this its ok and alerts prperly the value of new cost

   $("ul#shipping_method li span.amount").text(newCost); // when i set this it is returning NAN in the span value

  } 
});
```

I am getting the value of newcost, which  i have checked using alert, but when i try to set the new cost to the span tag it sets NAN.

Many Thanks

Comment: Debug your code by using `console.log()` to log the various values to the console. This will help you find your error.

Comment: where will i get the log messages?

Comment: @vikashbhartia Within your Browser Developer Tool console.

Comment: Your browser has bulit-in developer tools that includes a console that displays error messages. You just need to find and open the dev tools. Which browser are you using?

Comment: it is not showing any messages, the newCost variable here is getting the value because in first alert it shows the value. but then immediately second alert pops up with nan and the value is not shown.

Comment: @vikashbhartia: I don't know where your alerts are.

Comment: My alerts are only after the line  var newCost = ((parseFloat(res[1])*50)/100) + parseFloat(res[1]);

Comment: can you show the html?

Comment: Please edit your question to show exactly what you're doing.

Comment: the problem is coming when m using the last statement, which is $("ul#shipping_method li span.amount").text(newCost);

Comment: while setting the value it is having problem

Answer (score -1):

What is the value of new cost which you are getting in alert?

try parsing the value of the span while setting it.

```
var newCost = parseFloat(((parseFloat(res[1])*50)/100) + parseFloat(res[1]));
```

Comment: I am first getting the correct value in the alert, but when i click the ok button in that alert immediately another alert comes up with NAN

Comment: have you used any library that applies to the span which parses the values ?

Comment: please share your html